# Re-defining the same enum on every object oriented interface in C#

Tags: c#, interface

In olden days, you often had a data module that was "low level", did not depend on any other modules, but could be referenced by them, for example to get enums that were used throughout the system.
Now we have object oriented interfaces between modules, with calls and events. 
My question is, shouldn't we still have one place where enums that are used throughout the system are defined, and these enums should be referenced by every interface that needs them?

I have seen software where essentially the same enum is re-defined on each interface, with translation functions for when it is passed on to another module.

So for example, the interface IModule1 might have

```
enum module1_state
{
    Unknown, 
    NotRunning,
    Running
}
```

and the interface IModule2 might have

```
enum module2_state
{
    Unknown,
    NotRunning,
    Running
}
```

where module 1 for example collects data, module 2 performs some logic, and then passes data further to a 3rd module, e.g. a GUI.

In many cases, the enums would be genuinely different, because for example, the 2nd module can abstract away some information that isn't needed by the 3rd module, and pass on a simplified version.
But in some cases, they aren't different, and here it seems wrong to me that the enums are still re-defined on each interface.
An example is an action that is carried out as part of several different use cases.  The action is the same, but depending on the use case, several small details are different.  An enum carrying details of the use case is passed over an interface to a high level logic module, and then on over another interface to a lower level module.  It is redefined on each interface, and therefore must be translated in the high level logic module.

There are some other modules which just translate older, existing interfaces to newer ones, and again, both interfaces have re-defined the same enum.

Can anyone tell me which is best practice?

Comment: Is it possible that you will need to add a new value to `module1_state` (or, generally, modify it somehow), but not to `module2_state`? Also, could you give an example situation where you need to translate between the two enums?

Comment: Enums are simple values, they don't support anything resembling inheritance.  There's no mechanism to extend an existing enum type and add additional values.  Trying to force-fit that onto an enum is a mistake and will get you in trouble.

Comment: @svick I added a description.  The code is not always ideal (developed over long time etc), but I wondered why it seems to be taboo in some people's minds to have a publicly available enum that can be used anywhere in the code.

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks for your comment.  I am happy to re-define enums that really are different, that's not an issue - but I don't really understand why enums that are the same have to be redefined to an identical enum just because it is on a different interface.

Comment: Say you extend your code and you need to add an extra enum value to support a new feature of one of the interfaces.  What will you do with the extra enum value in the other interface implementations that didn't acquire the same feature?

Comment: That would be a good case for re-defining the enum.  But what if I extend the code, and the identical enum is used on another interface?  Do I have to re-define it then as well?

Comment: Your question is a bit too generic. I don't think you can really decide what is best without more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a matter of code organization, modularity and reuse. It might make sense for two modules to reuse a third (think projects in the same solution), but if they're part of separate [bounded contexts](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/91) (think solutions), they evolve independently and should generally use separate definitions. The mapping that you see should be normal between separate bounded contexts, but the enums should possibly be unified within the same context.

Comment: Both answers were helpful, but I hate leaving questions not marked as answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

The modern DLL mechanism of C# and Java both allow refactoring to move common things -- in the case of your question, the enums -- into a common DLL shared by the others; as you point out, taking advantage of this seems like a no brainer.

Still, as many of us know, the shape and architecture of code tends to reflect the shape and architecture of the responsible organizations (Conway's Law, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conways_Law); code is not just about meeting the requirements, but about  authorship, control & blame (schedules & project management), and responsibility for maintenance; these cause the structure of code to reflect the structure of the org chart.

(See, also, http://blogs.gartner.com/ray_valdes/2008/09/19/organizational-structure-vs-product-architecture-which-one-wins/)

So, when I see something like you're describing, I wonder if there's some org structure and politics in play.  Someone would have to own the common DLL, and neither org may want to be dependent upon the other; the result could be such replication.